# How to enable Heap updates on my android client

Tags: android

Under `DDMS`, there is a `HEAP` tab, and then I click my android application under 'Devices'. 
But it said:

```
Heap updates are NOT ENABLED for this client
```

How can I enable Heap update for my android application?

Answer (score 230, accepted):

On the devices tab, there are a bunch of icons starting with a green bug.  To the right of that is the "Update Heap: button which looks like a green cylinder that is half full.  Press that button and the heap tab should be enabled.  Click "Cause GC" to populate the Heap tab.

[image]

Comment: NB future readers: You have to select your process from the list first.

Comment: For future readers: In eclipse you have to click Window -> Open Perspective -> DDMS, in order to open the DDMS perspective. There you have a lot of windows popping up - including a devices tab (the one that they're talking about).

Comment: Do you ever run into the issue where your app does not appear under your device? Sometimes my app appears, and I can click the "Update Heap" button, but often times there are zero running processes listed under my device.

Comment: How Android studio will be more efficient here?

Comment: @Shubh I'm not sure that reply related directly to heap updates.  The original comment is gone and I don't remember the exact question.

Comment: What does GC stands for?

Comment: @YagneshCangi GC is Garbage Collection

Answer (score 3):

It is worth to mention one thing, you have to put in `android:debuggable="true"` in the `AndroidManifest.xml` (under Application tag) in order to see the process list appear under the available device/simulator (in DDMS). Even though you are not trying to run your application in debug mode.

Comment: That is not true, you only need this flag if you want to debug release-builds.