# GcWatcher.finalize timed out after 10 seconds

Tags: android, exception, garbage-collection

What is the reason for this exception? I have an activity with few videos running in it. Got puzzled. Please help.

```
06-15 11:00:33.775 E/AndroidRuntime(11757): FATAL EXCEPTION: FinalizerWatchdogDaemon
06-15 11:00:33.775 E/AndroidRuntime(11757): java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: com.android.internal.os.BinderInternal$GcWatcher.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
06-15 11:00:33.775 E/AndroidRuntime(11757):         at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
06-15 11:00:33.775 E/AndroidRuntime(11757):         at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
06-15 11:00:33.775 E/AndroidRuntime(11757):         at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102)
06-15 11:00:33.775 E/AndroidRuntime(11757):         at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73)
06-15 11:00:33.775 E/AndroidRuntime(11757):         at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170)
06-15 11:00:33.775 E/AndroidRuntime(11757):         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Its a very large app, if u can tell me what part of the code can be useful to be seen, I can paste it here. We work with Activities containing fragments, and these fragments play videos in loops.

Comment: Did you ever solved this ? i"m Seeing it on kitkat devices, very rare.

Comment: Were you debugging heap dumps in DDMS?

Comment: @Submersed I was debugging heap dumps in DDMS and got this error, do you think its a potential bug?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have enabled Heap Updates, so each method is a bit slower (or pretty much slower in case of media, like images, animations, video).

Here is a relevant link:
[How to Enable Heap Updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999087/how-to-enable-heap-updates-on-my-android-client)

Comment: so what is the solution?