# Unable to see heap updates on eclipse

Tags: android, android-emulator

With the objective of memory analysis, I was trying to get on with the heap usage on DDMS perspective. Unfortunately, even after carefully following instructions mentioned in many community posts, I could hardly get in on.

Here is what I have done so far.

```
a. Open DDMS > Devices
b. Select the process (application package) and enable 'Update Heap' button
c. Open Heap View to see heap usage.
```

I am attaching a screenshot for more clarity.

[image]

What is it preventing heap from showing up? Any clue?

Comment: according to android doc you need to click **Cause GC** to see heap updates

Comment: Cause GC is greyed out in Heap View!

Comment: Look here, first answer worked for me

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999087/how-to-enable-heap-updates-on-my-android-client

Tine

Comment: chek  here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999087/how-to-enable-heap-updates-on-my-android-client

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in ADT, there are two bug reports related to this issue.
I've updated SDK tools to version 22.05 and issue is fixed for me.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55517

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55394